# Overlapping abstract, keywords and section headers in IEEEtran document, "conference" and "compsoc" options set

Tags: ieeetran

I'm trying to format a paper to submit to an IEEE conference, using the `IEEEtran` document class. I've tried reading the [How-To](http://sites.ieee.org/wfiot-2018/files/2017/07/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), but I'm finding that tough to follow.

Basically my problem is that the vertical spacing seems to be all messed up. The abstract overlaps the section heading "1. Introcuction", and the keywords appear in between the section heading and the text of the introduction.

Removing `compsoc` in the arguments to the documentclass fixes the problem, but my conference is "Technically Co-Sponsored by IEEE Computer Society", so I should probably use their format, right?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{The most interesting paper ever}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Someone}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{Somewhere}
}

\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{%
\begin{abstract}
TODO: write abstract

blah blah
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    keyword1, keyword2
\end{IEEEkeywords}}

\maketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\else
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\fi
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} this is my introduction ipsum lorem etcetera and so on
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: use `ieeeconf` class or better find the author's kit for that special conference for the preferred class file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `compsoc` papers are *not* supposed to display `abstract` or `index` components if the `conference` option is set. However, your paper does contain these two components, and they end up getting overprinted by the section header because of the `\IEEEraisesectionheading` directive.

The two quickest solutions I can think of are (a) to simply delete (or comment out) the

```
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
```

directive, thereby not printing the abstract and index parts at all, or (b) to reorganize the `\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc ... \fi` block so that (i) both `conference` and `compsoc` are conditioning events, and (ii) the `\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext` instruction occurs together with the unraised section heading:

```
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \ifCLASSOPTIONconference
        \IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
        \section{Introduction}
        \label{sec:introduction}
    \else
        \IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
    \fi
\else
    \IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{sec:introduction}
\fi
```

Comment: great answer, thanks! I actually extended your option (b) with a nested if statement so that the introduction is only raised if it is a compsoc paper, but not a conference. Would you mind if I edit your answer to have the full nested if statement?

Comment: @craq - Go right ahead. :-)